# What is the name of this variant of the bubble sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

What is the name of the sort algorithm shown in the below gif?

[image: Sort Algorithm]

**Update:**

The simplest form goes through the whole list each time:

Pseudocode:

```
procedure cocktailShakerSort( A : list of sortable items ) defined as:
  do
    swapped := false
    for each i in 0 to length( A ) - 2 do:
      if A[ i ] > A[ i + 1 ] then // test whether the two elements are in the wrong order
        swap( A[ i ], A[ i + 1 ] ) // let the two elements change places
        swapped := true
      end if
    end for
    if not swapped then
      // we can exit the outer loop here if no swaps occurred.
      break do-while loop
    end if
    swapped := false
    for each i in length( A ) - 2 to 0 do:
      if A[ i ] > A[ i + 1 ] then
        swap( A[ i ], A[ i + 1 ] )
        swapped := true
      end if
    end for
  while swapped // if no elements have been swapped, then the list is sorted
end procedure
```

Comment: Info: you can find the answer by [reverse Google search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiseSQznev1KuIOfy4dyquRO6bBvJyPC8Dx_1WaCb84jWf0TYwu8c20VW5iS4QlSvtMZMN8PqP0xjTkm9v6A4RUWooATMrzkI_1_1qDoC4y_1djlwWrSw3vvU1ytaCpBhTm0kwQI59SHs5jZROD1kGFCEIgn-a8ZHpJFWwb9NJSFIkwLbeeicXhSSMSxS1FOSzuyIp0gWgk-zvh2j7GSGt4s8Hm15Vwyu5haLlDj3BWklRnXrAWiZ_1L7k2ZfjsBLccyO2WWabFw_1cqzGAoiSzC2sxIeNfNjVCTSRzEc87AbsRXKnBHmqkEQ2eowWlw5oHZYskimXwbKa).

Comment: The question would be more useful if you describe what the algorithm does **in text**, possibly with a pseudocode.

Comment: This is off-topic, by the way. [Are "What is this thing called?" questions on-topic for Stack Overflow? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277508/are-what-is-this-thing-called-questions-on-topic-for-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like Cocktail Sort which is a variation of Bubble sort. The Bubble sort algorithm always traverses elements from left and moves the largest element to its correct position in the first iteration and second largest in the second iteration and so on. Cocktail Sort traverses through a given array in both directions alternatively.

**Algorithm**:
Each iteration of the algorithm is broken up into 2 stages:

1-The first stage loops through the array from left to right, just like the Bubble Sort. During the loop, adjacent items are compared and if the value on the left is greater than the value on the right, then values are swapped. At the end of the first iteration, the largest number will reside at the end of the array.

2-The second stage loops through the array in opposite direction- starting from the item just before the most recently sorted item, and moving back to the start of the array. Here also, adjacent items are compared and are swapped if required.

The algorithm needs to complete this whole pass without any swap to know it is sorted.

Time complexities are same, but Cocktail performs better than Bubble Sort. Typically cocktail sort is less than two times faster than bubble sort. Consider the example (2, 3, 4, 5, 1). Bubble sort requires four traversals of array for this example, while Cocktail sort requires only two traversals.

Answer (score 1):

It *looks* like a bi-directional bubble sort<sup>(a)</sup>. You move an element (via swapping with its successor) from left to right until you find a bigger one, then you continue moving that one instead.

The only twist from a "normal" bubble sort is that alternate passes are in different directions, something that helps with a mostly sorted data set when you just tack a random value on the end then bubble-sort the whole thing.

Having said that, and assuming you didn't do that animation on your own, surely the site where you got it from would have some indication of what it was, yes? :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Which is *apparently* called a cocktail sort (in reference to the way you shake a cocktail shaker) although, in my rather *long* career, I've never heard it referred to as such.

Comment: There's even a Wikipedia article with the same visualization, called [Cocktail-Shaker-Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort)